# Syntaxlistpool.free separated syntax builder. While scaffolding Asp.Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

All packages are update till today, and using EF Core Code first. But while scaffolding API controller.

> Syntaxlistpool.free separated syntax builder. While scaffolding
>   Asp.Net Core 2.1

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the version of Microsost.CodeAnalysis.Common referenced in your project. I had version 2.9.0 but needed 2.8.0. Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common requires version 2.8.0. If you have the same problem then you will see this error in Visual studio's NuGet reference.

I would also recommend ensuring visual studio, asp.net core, .net core are up to date

Comment: I think my problem was that I had upgraded Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common to 2.9.0. Once I updated it to 2.8.2 my problem was solved. Thanks.